# Kotlin: trouble understanding generics

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a model implementing two interfaces

```
interface A
interface B
class Model() : A, B
```

When I  pass one parameter as a List of my Model class, compiler understands that Model is A and B. But when I pass two parameters, where one of them is given with the type T (where T: A, T: B), compiler cant understand it.

```
protected fun <T> test(givenList: List<T>) where T : A, T : B {

    val testList = ArrayList<Model>()
    oneParamFunc(testList) // will compile
    oneParamFunc(givenList) // will compile

    twoParamFunc(givenList, testList) // won't  compile (inferred type Any is not a subtype of A)
    twoParamFunc<T>(givenList, testList) // won't compile (Required List<T>, Found ArrayList<Model>)
}

protected fun <T> oneParamFunc(list: List<T>) where T : A, T : B { }
protected fun <T> twoParamFunc(oldList: List<T>, newList: List<T>) where T : A, T : B { }
```

What do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T` and `Model` may not be the same types. As such, you will need separate generic parameters for each list parameter:

```
fun <T1, T2> twoParamFunc(oldList: List<T1>, newList: List<T2>)
        where T1 : A, T1 : B, T2 : A, T2 : B { }
```